# My single image is not getting display on the TV

Tags: ios, objective-c, chromecast, google-cast

I am sending a single image to the receiver and want to display the image on the TV. But my TV screen is only showing the Black window. What am I missing? Someone help me.

```
HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> received: {"requestId":0,"status":{"applications":[{"appId":"3D307B85","displayName":"Photogenie","isIdleScreen":false,"namespaces":[{"name":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.photogenie.custom"},{"name":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.inject"}],"sessionId":"7E9F5C8F-317B-4895-8283-1CD2389012EC","statusText":"Application is starting","transportId":"web-1"}],"volume":{"controlType":"attenuation","level":1.0,"muted":false,"stepInterval":0.05000000074505806}},"type":"RECEIVER_STATUS"}
2016-07-05 15:12:10.205 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> Received device status with requestID=0
2016-07-05 15:12:10.206 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> checking if app is stopped
2016-07-05 15:12:10.207 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> checking receiver status for changes; status was requested? 0
2016-07-05 15:12:10.207 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> <0x12ee222e0> castSocket:<0x174173ec0> didReceiveMessage:<0800120a 72656365 69766572 2d301a01 2a222375 726e3a78 2d636173 743a636f 6d2e676f 6f676c65 2e636173 742e7265 63656976 65722800 32d8037b 22726571 75657374 4964223a 302c2273 74617475 73223a7b 22617070 6c696361 74696f6e 73223a5b 7b226170 70496422 3a223344 33303742 3835222c 22646973 706c6179 4e616d65 223a2250 686f746f 67656e69 65222c22 69734964 6c655363 7265656e 223a6661 6c73652c 226e616d 65737061 63657322 3a5b7b22 6e616d65 223a2275 726e3a78 2d636173 743a636f 6d2e676f 6f676c65 2e636173 742e7068 6f746f67 656e6965 2e637573 746f6d22 7d2c7b22 6e616d65 223a2275 726e3a78 2d636173 743a636f 6d2e676f 6f676c65 2e636173 742e696e 6a656374 227d5d2c 22736573 73696f6e 4964223a 22374539 46354338 462d3331 37422d34 3839352d 38323833 2d314344 32333839 30313245 43222c22 73746174 75735465 7874223a 22417070 6c696361 74696f6e 20737461 74757320 69732072 65616479 2e2e2e22 2c227472 616e7370 6f727449 64223a22 7765622d 31227d5d 2c22766f 6c756d65 223a7b22 636f6e74 726f6c54 79706522 3a226174 74656e75 6174696f 6e222c22 6c657665 6c223a31 2e302c22 6d757465 64223a66 616c7365 2c227374 6570496e 74657276 616c223a 302e3035 30303030 30303037 34353035 3830367d 7d2c2274 79706522 3a225245 43454956 45525f53 54415455 53227d>
2016-07-05 15:12:10.210 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> received: {"requestId":0,"status":{"applications":[{"appId":"3D307B85","displayName":"Photogenie","isIdleScreen":false,"namespaces":[{"name":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.photogenie.custom"},{"name":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.inject"}],"sessionId":"7E9F5C8F-317B-4895-8283-1CD2389012EC","statusText":"Application status is ready...","transportId":"web-1"}],"volume":{"controlType":"attenuation","level":1.0,"muted":false,"stepInterval":0.05000000074505806}},"type":"RECEIVER_STATUS"}
2016-07-05 15:12:10.211 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> Received device status with requestID=0
2016-07-05 15:12:10.211 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> checking if app is stopped
2016-07-05 15:12:10.212 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> checking receiver status for changes; status was requested? 0
2016-07-05 15:12:10.213 HelloVideoGoogleCastObjectiveC[1791:389018] The Message is --> status text has changed; calling delegate
```

Some one help me. What am I missing? I don't know what output should come. Why is my single image not getting display on the TV? I have created a custom receiver.html and filled on the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have posted multiple questions around the same issue that you are running into, please stop doing that.

Based on your log, you are sending an image in a serialized format, in a "message". I don't know why you expect that to work; look at the answer in your other post to see what the proper way is (i.e. using an embedded local web server in your sender app to serve the image to chromecast).